# Wordpress Site work fine on localhost but on live it shows "/Lucky Was Here @Cyber Oportunis" Error

Tags: wordpress

I have issue with my wordpress site. At localhost, there is no problem with the site but when i upload the whole site at online server almost every page/post do not show any content but show this specific error

> "/Lucky Was Here
>
> @Cyber Oportunis"

Also, in title bar, there is written

> "Hacked By ./Lucky"

I have changed the theme a couple of time but have same issue.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: Looks like you've been hacked...I think this is the wrong forum for this....

Comment: I would change your FTP password and try uploading again.

Answer (score 0):

You've been hacked.
http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Change passwords (WP+FTP), export your posts, delete database, do a fresh install, scan all plug-ins and themes for malware before reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through wp_options table in your database, is any changes done at there or not.